# Crsytal Report not working in Windows Server 2012

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using Crystal Reports `version 11.0.0.895`, `Visual Studio 2013`. I populated data using `SQL query`, saved to datatable and shown in the report. This report is working fine on developer machine (`Windows 7`) and able export the report to `PDF` format, but when deploy the window application to the client machine (`windows server 2012`), the report show error and not able to export report to `PDF` format.
Is there any component i missed out and need to be installed?

**Error Message show as below:**

> "Input string was not in a correct format"

**OR**

> Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than size       of the argument list

**Server Configuration as below:**

```
- Windows Server 2012 R2  ,64 bit
- Crystal reports for .net framework 2.0 (64 bit)
- Crystal reports for .net framework 2.0 (86 bit)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have Read your Question You want to Just Do the Following Things
Go to the References And Select all the necessary reference to the Crystal Report Then Go to properties or F4 for Properties tab Then Set Specific version to false then Build the Solution..